# Why is the ggplot2 installation failing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to install the ggplot2 package, so that I make use of ggplot function for my graphs but it keeps failing me. Where is the problem?

```
>  install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Augustinho/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ggplot2  3.3.0  3.3.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.stat.unipd.it/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3035612 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: package 'vctrs' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Augustinho/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\Augustinho\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpM7MaYn\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In readRDS(dest) : lzma decoding result 10
2: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: `error: package 'vctrs' not found` suggests you should try `install.packages("vctrs")`.

Comment: @GregorThomas That should not be necessary, as R installs dependencies automatically. OP should simply install the binary rather than the source package (why R doesn’t install dependencies for source packages is frankly beyond me).

Answer (score 0):

As you are on Windows, try to install the binary version with dependencies:

```
install.packages("ggplot2",
                 type = "binary",
                 dependencies = TRUE,
                 repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

#### Edit:

Helped first running:

```
install.packages("vctrs", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

to skip some `vctrs` installation error.

Comment: is the any other alternative way of installing the packages? the method above keeps failling me.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba Oh, that's strange. What is your error message for this case, please?

Comment: > library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: package ‘vctrs’ not found
. that is the error I am getting.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba Yeah, that's the error message for loading the package. So the installation of ggplot2 with the code above was successful and only loading the package fails? Or did the installation throw any error?

Comment: yes when installing the packages, it say's vectors not found.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba So maybe try first running `install.packages("vctrs", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")` and then the command above.

Comment: that has worked and thank you very much. however one more last question. below is an error I am coming across with:lot(FM, aes(x=TYPE.OF.CRIME, y=HOUR)) +
+ geom_histogram() 
+ . why do i still have + sign. what could be missing perhaps. thanks.

Comment: > library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(df,aes(x=TYPE.OF.CRIME,y=HOUR))+
+ geom_histogram()
Error: stat_bin() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba Thanks for your feedback, I have updated the answer so that you can accept it. I don't know your data frame and I don't know the plot you want to get, but you maybe want rather `ggplot(df,aes(x = TYPE.OF.CRIME, y = HOUR)) + geom_col()` than histogram (as histogram automatically analyses the dataset and plots the counts/frequencies, so it takes only `x` in `aes()` function, while `geom_col()` will plot bars with type of crime on `x` axis and hour on `y` axis. If this does not help, just create a new question at SO with more details. :-) And wish you good luck with R!